# Is the module path the same as the import path?

Tags: go

The tour of Go at https://go.dev/tour/basics/1 says:

"This program is using the packages with import paths "fmt" and "math/rand". By convention, the package name is the same as the last element of the import path. For instance, the "math/rand" package comprises files that begin with the statement package rand."

But the last element of the package "quote"'s import path  is "v4". And when using the package the code is written as `quote.Go()`

What does the last element of a import path mean? Is it a directory? In the case of rsc.io/quote package, the last element is "v4" and it's not the same as the package name . When importing the package we write import rsc.io/quote/v4.

Is the module path the same as the import path?

Comment: 1. There is a fundamental difference between packages from the stdlib like math/rand and 3rd party libraries like rsc.io/quote. 2. Modules allow for versioning (and importing several different major versions in one code base) that's why module names end in major version numbers (at least for versions >= 2). The "last element of a module name" is an optional major version suffix.

Comment: 3. "Import path" is a concept that applies only to packages. You cannot import a module (really, wait, this will make sense). 4. A module may contain on or more packages. If a module contains just one package at the root of the module the import path of that package is the module name (only). Remember (see 2.) that the module name may (must vor v>=2) end in a major version suffix. 5. If a module contains several packages they will live in some relative path some/rel/path in the module and their import path will be <module-name>/rel/import/path

Comment: Summing up: You import packages. Modules allow to group packages and version them together. A package by itself has no version. A module has a name, this name must end in the major version (optional for v1). The import path of a 3rd party library package thus looks like <module-base-name>/v<major-version>/<path/of/package/relative/to/module/repo/root>. Parts optional as needed. The stdlib packages are versioned together with your Go installation.

Comment: It's a strong _convention_ to have package names equal the last (non-version-identifier) component of the import path. One-package-only-modules are rare. Do not take any convention too literal. Yes, module identifiers end in version number but it should be clear that this version number is not the package name.

Comment: maybe reading this can also help to understand https://go.dev/ref/mod#versions

Comment: This section of the module series also explains how major versions are handled: https://go.dev/blog/v2-go-modules